# ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set

Tags: authentication, redis, jedis

I am using jedis 2.8.0 and getting following exception:

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:123)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:157)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:211)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:196)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.auth(BinaryJedis.java:2049)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:89)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:458)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
        ... 4 more
```

Following is the api I am using:

```
jedisPool = new JedisPool(jedisPoolConfig, host, port, IDLE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, authSecret);
```

Notes:

1. I am able to successfully send commands to redis using the exact
   same password using the redis-cli -a option.
2. I  also printed the password in the logs to see if I am sending wrong 
   password, but the password passed to JedisPool is proper.
3. I also tried to "redis-cli monitor" calls on redis but I dont see any AUTH
   request.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no password set in your `Redis` instance. Password sent with  `redis-cli -a` is just being ignored.

Now, you may set the password in redis instance. To do so, edit redis configuration file, set `requirepass` option and restart redis instance.

Or, just ignore password option while communicating with redis. E.g.

```
jedisPool = new JedisPool(jedisPoolConfig, host, port, IDLE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
```

Comment: Thats correc. I was using multiple redis layers..in one layer AUTH was enabled and another not.

Answer (score 3):

This will might work if you don't want to set the password.
[image]

```
spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1 
spring.redis.port=6379 
spring.redis.password=
```

Leave the password field as blank.

OR

Use the requirepass a password option

redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH PASSWORD

(error) ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set.

redis 127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET requirepass "mypass"

> > OK

redis 127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH mypass

> > OK

Comment: Didn't work for me using Jedis. Leaving the password empty still caused the same exception. What worked for me is just configuring the password using requirepass in the redis.conf